# What is the meaning of ノ in the videogame title 二ノ国?

Tags: particle-の

This question stems from the name of the game: Ni No Kuni which in Japanese is 二ノ国.

1. Why there is no in Katakana here?  Is this still the particle の?
2. If so, then does this form a Genitive, Ordinal Number, or something else, like "The Country of Two" vs "The Second Country" or maybe "Another Country"?

I'm not sure what the intended meaning is here.

Comment: Isn't it 仁ノ国?  (serious question)

Comment: No, the game's title is definitely [二ノ国](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8C%E3%83%8E%E5%9B%BD).

Comment: @jogloran #TheMoreYouKnow

Comment: @istrasci  The More You Know

Comment: @jogloran ⭐  How did I miss that one?    Also, I think I was confusing it with the game 仁王.

Comment: related: [What does ni no kuni mean exactly?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19218/what-does-ni-no-kuni-mean-exactly)

Answer (score 5):

### Usage of の

The particle の connects two nouns, where one modifies the other.

While it is true that in many instances this denotes a relation of possession (genitive):

> AのB。"B belongs to A"

> 私の名前 "My name"

it is not always the case, and の may indicate any relationship or connection between both nouns arbitrarily. The nature of this relationship is determined by context, like many other aspects in Japanese:

> 司会のミラーさん。"Moderator Miller" (A is qualifying or describing B)

> 男の人。 "A man" (Again A is qualifying B)

Note that among learners of Japanese as a foreign language, there's a whole category of the so called "の adjectives", where an "adjective" modifies a noun connected by the の particle. From the standpoint of Japanese grammar, there's no such category and the supposed "の adjectives" are simply nouns, that happen to modify other nouns by connecting both with の.

### The particular case of 二ノ国

To answer your first question, "Is this still the particle の ?" the answer is yes, ノ in 二ノ国 corresponds to the particle の without a doubt.

I found [this entry](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/19218/what-does-ni-no-kuni-mean-exactly) in the sister site anime.stackexchange.com where they try to determine the meaning of the title. The accepted answer states that:

> So the final title is either: "The Country of Two" [...] or "Second Country"

I checked the [entry for 二ノ国 at the Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%8C%E3%83%8E%E5%9B%BD). It turns out that besides 二ノ国, there is also an 一ノ国. Since there are actually 2 countries, it only makes sense to translate 二ノ国 as "Second Country" or "Country number two" rather than "The country of two":

> シズクは現実世界（『**一ノ国**』）とは異なる並行世界**二ノ国**からやってきたのだという。**一ノ国**と**二ノ国**はそこに暮らすものの魂が繋がる表裏一体の世界だった。

> Shizuku is said to have come from a parallel world called **Ni no Kuni**, which is different from the real world ("**Ichi no Kuni**"). **Ichi no Kuni** and **Ni no Kuni** were two sides of the same world where the souls of those who lived there were connected.

### A note on numbers in Japanese

Please note that 二ノ国 is not the common way to count stuff in Japanese. Usually, to count objects in Japanese you should use counters. This is a complex topic and I can't explain it here, just beware that numberのnoun is not the only nor the standard way to count things in Japanese. Here you are some examples of numbers combined with nouns (counters in **bold** font):

> **三{み}つ**のミカン Three mandarines (general counter)

> 三{さん}**番{ばん}目{め}** の車 The car in the 3rd position (ordinal counter)

> 第{だい}3**課{か}** The 3rd lesson (counter for lessons)

> 三{さん}**月{がつ}** The 3rd month, March (counter for months)

> 三{さん}**ヵ月{げつ}** Three months (counter for months)

There is a counter for countries, with the same kanji 国, but it is pronounced 国{こく} instead of 国{くに}. However, this counter does not seem to be used regularly (see the [discussion in the comments section](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/96531/what-is-the-meaning-of-%e3%83%8e-in-the-videogame-title-%e4%ba%8c%e3%83%8e%e5%9b%bd/96557#comment157273_96557)):

> [三{さん}**国{ごく}**](https://jisho.org/search/%E4%B8%89%E5%9B%BD) Three countries (counter for countries).

Comment: Generally speaking, 国 is better understood as "land" or "world" in many cases.

Comment: Yes, not only in general, but in this particular case it also makes more sense to understand 一ノ国 and 二ノ国  as "lands" or "worlds" rather than "countries". So probably "the second world" is better than "second country".

Comment: Is it really accurate to say that 国{こく} by itself is a *counter* for countries? I know it appears combined with numbers in words like 三国{さんごく}, as well as in compounds like 三国同盟 , but I'm not convinced it's functioning as a 助数詞 in either of those cases. And when a number of countries is being specified in a general context, I think I usually see ~ヶ国 (or ~か国), or else [some number] + の + 国々. For example, the Japanese Wikipedia page for G20 says "G20（ジートゥエンティ）は、'Group of Twenty' の略で、G7に参加する7ヶ国、EU、ロシア、および新興国11ヶ国の計20の国々と地域から成るグループである".  Also, my dictionary also lacks an entry for 国 as a counter.

Comment: @Nanigashi, I'm afraid that beyond a couple of resources backing my statement I can't really argue your point. I am not experienced with using 国 as a counter, but given that the question is about countries (or worlds) and involves numbers, I thought it was a good idea to lookup whether there's a specific counter for countries, and that in my answer is what I found. Rereading the source, it really reinforces your point that 国 is not used as a regular 助数詞, however this didn't prevent the authors of such article to deem it a counter anyways.

Comment: [350 Japanese counters grouped by usefulness](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/japanese-counters-list): "国 is used for counting countries. It's mostly used in older titles and for idioms. You may also see 箇国 or ヶ国, which are used when the speaker or writer is emphasizing a single country. [....] ヶ国 is used to count the number of individual countries. If you're just generally counting countries, just the counter 国 will be fine."

Comment: [国の数え方](https://count.jitenon.jp/word/p408): Both 国 and ヶ国 are listed as counters.

Comment: To be clear, I'm not saying 国 definitely can't be used as a counter; I'm not a native speaker, and I honestly don't know! But I don't recall ever seeing it used that way, and when I checked a couple of dictionaries they didn't seem to confirm that it could. A couple of very quick Google searches didn't turn up any usage examples, either, apart from special cases like ひょうご五国 (where 国 refers not to countries but to regions of 兵庫県that correspond to provinces of premodern Japan) or common terms like 三国 or 五代十国, which refer to *specific groups* of countries or kingdoms. (Great answer overall, BTW.)

Comment: I'm on the same page than you, I've seen and used ヶ国 myself but had no idea about  国, and the resource where I found it says it's "mostly used in older titles and for idioms", so your point absolutely makes sense. I've just edited my answer to warn about this point, in case someone skims through it and doesn't bother reading the comments.

Comment: `numberのnoun` is not standard but not totally unheard of, either. [二の矢](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%BA%8C%E3%81%AE%E7%9F%A2/) ("second arrow") is an idiom meaning something like "another string" or "plan B".

Comment: Plenty of stations, names and locations use ノ or の as well. 二ノ宮、江の島、一ノ瀬、龍ノ介、宮ノ下、五ノ三、森の里. For place names, usually the use of ノ over の　indicates the time the name was given the "no".

Answer (score -1):

Well, the quick and easy answer, it is just being used as katakana to be pretty.
No actual reason.
Like in the pic:
[image: Like here]